# Update value in table with 'select query' in where condition using Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a query like this

```
    SELECT DISTINCT  A.BRANCH_ID,
               A.BRANCH_FINANCE_ID,
               A.PRODUCT_ID,
               A.INSENTIF_AMOUNT,
               MAX (A.TGL_START) TGL_START,
               B.BRANCH_NAME
        FROM      MST_INSENTIF_OWNER A
               LEFT JOIN
                  MST_BRANCH_FINANCE_COMPANY B
               ON A.BRANCH_FINANCE_ID = B.BRANCH_FINANCE_ID
       WHERE       A.BRANCH_ID = 002
               AND B.BRANCH_NAME LIKE '%ADIRA%'
               AND A.BRANCH_FINANCE_ID = 'FIN.13.00000054'
    GROUP BY   A.BRANCH_ID,
               A.BRANCH_FINANCE_ID,
               A.PRODUCT_ID,
               A.INSENTIF_AMOUNT,
               B.BRANCH_NAME
```

It display 174 total rows, Then I want to make update from that table like this

```
     /* Formatted on 1/6/2017 11:33:51 AM (QP5 v5.115.810.9015) */
UPDATE   MST_INSENTIF_OWNER S
   SET   INSENTIF_AMOUNT = 1
 WHERE   EXISTS
            (  SELECT   A.BRANCH_ID,
                        A.BRANCH_FINANCE_ID,
                        A.PRODUCT_ID,
                        A.INSENTIF_AMOUNT,
                        MAX (A.TGL_START) TGL_START,
                        B.BRANCH_NAME
                 FROM      MST_INSENTIF_OWNER A
                        LEFT JOIN
                           MST_BRANCH_FINANCE_COMPANY B
                        ON A.BRANCH_FINANCE_ID = B.BRANCH_FINANCE_ID
                WHERE       A.BRANCH_ID = 002
                        AND B.BRANCH_NAME LIKE '%ADIRA%'
                        AND A.BRANCH_FINANCE_ID = 'FIN.13.00000054'
             GROUP BY   A.BRANCH_ID,
                        A.BRANCH_FINANCE_ID,
                        A.PRODUCT_ID,
                        A.INSENTIF_AMOUNT,
                        B.BRANCH_NAME)
```

But it makes all the record in MST_INSENTIF_OWNER update also. What is my wrong on this query ? :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why Oracle can not perform the update with join statement. Then when I got this MERGE from a forum it saved my day.

```
 /* Formatted on 1/6/2017 11:53:28 AM (QP5 v5.115.810.9015) */
    MERGE INTO   MST_INSENTIF_OWNER trg
         USING   (  SELECT   A.BRANCH_ID,
                             A.BRANCH_FINANCE_ID,
                             A.PRODUCT_ID,
                             A.INSENTIF_AMOUNT,
                             MAX (A.TGL_START) TGL_START,
                             B.BRANCH_NAME
                      FROM      MST_INSENTIF_OWNER A
                             LEFT JOIN
                                MST_BRANCH_FINANCE_COMPANY B
                             ON A.BRANCH_FINANCE_ID = B.BRANCH_FINANCE_ID
                     WHERE       A.BRANCH_ID = 002
                             AND B.BRANCH_NAME LIKE '%ADIRA%'
                             AND A.BRANCH_FINANCE_ID = 'FIN.13.00000054'
                  GROUP BY   A.BRANCH_ID,
                             A.BRANCH_FINANCE_ID,
                             A.PRODUCT_ID,
                             A.INSENTIF_AMOUNT,
                             B.BRANCH_NAME) src
            ON   (    trg.BRANCH_ID = src.BRANCH_ID
                  AND trg.BRANCH_FINANCE_ID = src.BRANCH_FINANCE_ID
                  AND trg.PRODUCT_ID = src.PRODUCT_ID
                  AND trg.TGL_START = src.TGL_START)
    WHEN MATCHED
    THEN
       UPDATE SET trg.INSENTIF_AMOUNT = 123;
```